# Cannot pip install anything with OS X El Capitan

Tags: python

I am trying to `pip install virtualenv` (and anything else) on OS X El Capitan and got the following error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 311, in run
    root=options.root_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 646, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 803, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 998, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 339, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 282, in clobber
    ensure_dir(dest)  # common for the 'include' path
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 71, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
```

Looks `pip` is trying to write in `'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages'` and due to SIP in El Capitan it got denied. 
But I was wondering why does `pip` needs to write there? How can I fix this?

I ran `brew doctor`
which gives

```
Your system is ready to brew.
```

So I think it is OK.

I tried `brew reinstall python` and it gives an odd error:

```
==> Reinstalling python
Error: /usr/local/opt/python is not a valid keg
```

`which python` gives

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

So where in system has this weird thing that let `pip` fail

Update:

It looks my `pip` is pointing to system python rather than brewed python.
I changed the first line of pip to

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
```

and problem is solved

Comment: try sudo pip install...

Comment: But I was told we should not use `sudo` for `pip` but I will try it any way

Comment: tried it but still the same error

Comment: If you don't want to install in a system wide location, why not try `pip install --user`?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to `brew link python`, or `unlink` then `link` to get things pointing to the correct places.